# Disable all ligature patterns in selnolig for ligatures not in latin modern

Tags: ligatures, latin-modern, selnolig

I would like to disable all patterns of the `selnolig` package which matches ligatures that are not available in latin modern. Am I correct that latin modern only has ligatures for: `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl`?

I need this functionality, because the output created by the option `debugon` of the `selnolig` package is very verbose due to pattern matches like `fb` and `ft` which are not ligatures in latin modern as far as I know. So after the pattern matches for these ligatures are disabled the output should be less verbose.

I tried a simple `\keeplig{fb}`, but this doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you use the English or German ligature suppression patterns (or both)?

Comment: @Mico I'm using the ngerman option of the `selnolig` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inhibit the package's ligature suppression rules for *all* `f[bhjkt]` instances while using the `ngerman` language option, I would like to suggest you take the following measures:

- Locate the files `selnolig.sty` and `selnolig-german-patterns.sty` in your TeX distribution. Make copies of these files, calling the copies (say) `selnolig-nofb.sty` and `selnolig-german-patterns-nofb.sty`, respectively. Save the copies either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by TeX; if you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Open the file `selnolig-nofb.sty` in a text editor and replace the instruction

  ```
        \RequirePackage{selnolig-german-patterns}
  ```

  (most likely on line 245, if you're using version 0.302 of the package) with

  ```
        \RequirePackage{selnolig-german-patterns-nofb}
  ```

  Furthermore, replace the instruction

  ```
  \ProvidesPackage{selnolig}[\selnoligpackagedate]
  ```

  on line 25 with

  ```
  \ProvidesPackage{selnolig-nofb}[\selnoligpackagedate]
  ```

  Save the file.
- Open the file `selnolig-german-patterns-nofb.sty` in a text editor and comment out (or delete, if you prefer) all lines of code in sections 8 thru 11 of the file. (That's lines 1472 thru 2018 in the current version of this file.)

  Save the file.
- Start using the modified `selnolig` package by loading it via the instruction

  ```
  \usepackage[ngerman]{selnolig-nofb}
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As the second solution seems to work, loading the package with `\usepackage[ngerman,noftligs]{selnolig}` and then setting `\debugon` didn't change `ft` pattern matches to occur in the output.

Comment: @user2653422 - Thanks for this feedback. Which version of the `selnolig` package do you use? I'll have to look into what's going on with the `noftligs` option.

Comment: It's version: `Version 0.302, Date 2015/10/26`

Comment: One additional thing I noticed for a `ft` pattern is that it's applied to the word `Schrift` breaking up the ligature (if I had the `ft` ligature). I think there is no morphene.

Comment: @user2653422 - I've deleted the entire first paragraph of my answer: The `noftligs` option suppresses `ft` ligatures globally and does not inhibit the operation of selnolig's rules for ft and fft cases. My bad.

Comment: @user2653422 - I'm not sure I understand your comment about the noun `Schrift`. For sure, the `ft` ligature in this word is *not* suppressed by `selnolig`, which is the correct setting (I would claim...). Please explain what you mean by "there is no morpheme"?

Comment: The debug output has a log for `Dissertationsschrift` claiming it will suppress the `ft` ligature. I think it should leave the ligature untouched.

Comment: @user2653422 - That's strange. I have selnolig version 0.302 as well. When I compile a test document containing just the word "Dissertationsschrift" (and the language option is "ngerman"), `selnolig` makes no attempt to suppress the `ft` ligature. Please report the lines from the log file that say that the ft ligature in "Dissertationsschrift" is being suppressed. I'm really curious as to which ligature suppression rule is being triggered.

Comment: The lines of the log are: `pattern match: Dissertationsschrift - ft` `Do ligature suppression for: Dissertationsschrift` `Inserting nolig whatsit before glyph: t` `Last char: t [1`. The only packages I've loaded were `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` `\usepackage[ngerman,noftligs]{selnolig}` and setting `\debugon` all within the normal article class.

Comment: @user2653422 - Thanks for this additional piece of information. The `noftligs` option suppresses all `ft` and `fft` ligatures -- globally. If you want only *selective* suppression of `ft` and `fft` ligatures (or no such ligature suppression at all, since your font doesn't feature these ligatures to begin with), don't set the `noftligs` option.

Comment: My fault, sorry I forget the `noftligs` option.